# Error showing in terminal instead of response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making a RESTful API with Express framework. I have setup a middleware but the error does no go into middleware
I have codes in following files:
in `router.js`

```
router.get('/budgets', verifyToken,  budgetController.getBudgets);
```

that `verifyToken` is a middleware to verify user token

in `verify_token.js`

```
const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.get("x-access-token");
  try {
    if (!token) {
       throw new Error('Token not found.');
    } else {
      jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, async (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          if (err instanceof jwt.TokenExpiredError) throw new Error('Token expired.');
        }else {
          const isUserExists = await User.findOne({_id: decoded.userId});
          if(!isUserExists) throw new Error("User not found.");
          req.user = decoded;
          return next();
        }
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('Internal server error.');
  }
};

module.exports = { verifyToken };
```

and in `app.js` I have following

```
app.use('/api/v1', budgetRoutes);

//middleware for error handling
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if(err) {
       return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});
```

But as response I am getting following in terminal (but i have setup to get response with error message as you have seen):

```
    C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\middlewares\is-auth.js:26
    throw new Error('Internal server error.');
          ^

Error: Internal server error.
    at verifyToken (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\middlewares\is-auth.js:26:11)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)    
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)   
    at router (C:\Users\Rintu\Desktop\Nodejs Practices\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Comment: Looks like you have no idea why `(err)` comes after `catch`. Why not just `console.log("ERROR:", err)` and see what's the issue??

Answer (score 1):

#### Difference between synchronous and asynchronous errors handling

From the Express documentation:

> For errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route handlers and middleware, you must pass them to the next() function, where Express will catch and process them.

Try replace

`throw new Error('Internal server error.');`

by

`next(new Error('Internal server error'));`.

You will need to do the same for other asynchronous errors.

I create a minimal example to illustrate the difference between synchronous and asynchronous error handling. Feel free to test it :)

#### Synchronous error - throw worked

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/',  (req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error("test");
    throw error;
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if(err) {
       return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});

app.listen(80, () => console.log("run"));
```

### Asynchronous error - throw doesn't work, use next!

Now if you use an async middleware (`app.post('/',  async(req, res, next) => {`), `throw` doesn't work anymore. You need to call `next(error)`, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/',  async (req, res, next) => { // <----------- async middleware
    const error = new Error("test");
    next(error); // <----------------- notice this line
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if(err) {
       return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});

app.listen(80, () => console.log("run"));
```